# Whole page gets replaced with a text "XSS" after a successful loop

Tags: javascript, json

When I tried to debug this, after the loop finishes, it always ends with the whole page getting replaced with a text "XSS", despite being able to properly populate everything. Attached is an image of before [image] and after [image]the loop finishes.

```js
//Populate
var table = document.getElementsByClassName("table")[0];

var col = [];
for (var i = 0; i < TABLE_DATA.length; i++) {
  for (var key in TABLE_DATA[i]) {
    if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
      col.push(key);
    }
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < TABLE_DATA.length; i++) {
  var row = table.insertRow(1);
  for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    var tabCell = row.insertCell(j);
    tabCell.innerHTML = TABLE_DATA[i][col[j]];
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title>Javascript Exercise</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h2>JavaScript Exercise</h2>
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <button id="start" type="button" class="btn btn-default">start random</button>
      <button id="stop" type="button" class="btn btn-default">stop random</button>
      <button id="sort" type="button" class="btn btn-default">sort</button>
    </div>
  </form>

  <div class="contents">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Image</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="json/data.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: xss usually means cross site scripting attack. check your provided data if there was such an attack made (see if there is <script> tags present). This assignment is probably a security assignment

Comment: I guess you have an [XSS vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) and some of the data in that table is tainted. Replace `tabCell.innnerHTML` with `tabCell.textContent` and you should be fine.

Comment: Interesting... it works! Thanks Vlaz!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a [Cross-site scripting (shortened to XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) vulnerability in your code and the data you put in the table is likely taking advantage of that.

The core of the issue is that when you assign a value to `.innerHTML` *anything* in the value is put as HTML, so if you have data that has, say, `<script>` tags then those would be attached to the DOM as-is and evaluated, then executed. Which allows an attacker to do anything they want on your page, including overwrite the entire page with "XSS".

```js
document.getElementById("replacer").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var replaceText = "<img src='nothing' "+
    "onerror='document.getElementById(\"do-not-touch\").innerHTML = \"oops\"'/>";
  
  document.getElementById("sample").innerHTML = replaceText;
})
```

```css
#do-not-touch {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#sample {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="do-not-touch">Replace the text below</div>
<div id="sample">Replace this text</div>
<button id="replacer">Click to replace text</button>
```

You can instead simply assign to [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerHTML) - if you do that, then the browser automatically sanitizes the values when putting them in the DOM and makes sure they are not going to be evaluated as HTML or JavaScript.

```js
document.getElementById("replacer").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var replaceText = "<img src='nothing' "+
    "onerror='document.getElementById(\"do-not-touch\").innerHTML = \"oops\"'/>";
    
  document.getElementById("sample").textContent = replaceText;
})
```

```css
#do-not-touch {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#sample {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="do-not-touch">Replace the text below</div>
<div id="sample">Replace this text</div>
<button id="replacer">Click to replace text</button>
```